# Text-friendly file format for structured data

Tags: html, json, xml, yaml

I'm looking for a file format that lets me encode structured data like dictionaries and arrays, but also allows me to easily edit text blocks, including line breaks.

Candidates so far:

- xml: (+) good for text editing and structured data, (-) ignores line breaks, closing tags is cumbersome
- html: (+) has tags for line breaks, (-) no structured data
- json: (+) good for structured data, (-) bad for editing multiline text
- yaml: (+) good for structured data, (-) bad for editing multiline text if text contains special characters like colon etc **[edit: see accepted answer, literal style works]**

My favorite so far: xml with self-defined tags for line breaks. Better ideas?

Comment: Kinda depends what you need it for. In a C#/Js Application I would recommend JSON because C# has good JSON javascriptserializers, But for a database I would recommend CSV, since you can define your own column and line breaks like that.

Comment: You can use Javascript with JSON, easily, to show data in html page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YAML is a perfect fit, and your "con" that it's "bad for editing multiline text if text contains special characters like colon etc" is entirely unfounded. YAML is by far the most featureful format for multi-line text:

```
---
# Block scalars are folded and stripped by default
preamble:
  We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more
  perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility,
  provide for the common defence, promote the general Welfare,
  and secure the Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our
  Posterity, do ordain and establish this Constitution for the
  United States of America.

# Chomping indicators (+ and -) allow explicit control over how
# leading/trailing whitespace will be preserved or stripped
chomp: >+


  Hello: Is it me you're looking for?



# Literal style preserves formatting
homepage: |
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>My kewl web site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </body>
  </html>

# The indentation indicator lets you explicitly control indentation if it
# can't be inferred
indentation: |4

            I'll be indented eight spaces
          I'll be indented six

# And colons (or other special characters) are not a problem
emoji: |
  : Grinning face {U+1F600}
  : Grimacing face {U+1F62C}
  : Disappointed face {U+1F61E}
```

...and, of course, you can use any of these formats within a mapping (dictionary) or sequence (array). You can even use complex strings (or any YAML structure, [as it happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987316/what-is-a-complex-mapping-key-in-yaml/34009604#34009604)) for mapping keys.

If you have an example of a use case that you think YAML is a poor fit for, feel free to leave a comment. YAML isn't perfect for everything, but it's great for a lot of things.

For comparison, here's the same thing in JSON:

```json
{ "preamble": "We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide for the common defence, promote the general Welfare, and secure the Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain and establish this Constitution for the United States of America.",
  "chomp": "\n\nHello: Is it me you're looking for?\n\n\n\n",
  "homepage": "<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>My kewl web site</title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <h1>Hello world!</h1>\n  </body>\n</html>\n",
  "indentation": "\n        I'll be indented eight spaces\n      I'll be indented six\n",
  "emoji": ": Grinning face {U+1F600}\n: Grimacing face {U+1F62C}\n: Disappointed face {U+1F61E}\n"
}
```